# How to render a dynamic number of GroupBoxes

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to do something like the following: for each contract, render a `GroupBox` with some info.

The number of contracts changes based on the selected company.

How would I accomplish something like this? The only dynamic GUI elements I've been able to implement or found help on are things like DataGridViews, which are bound directly to the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was looking for was the `DataRepeater` control. This lets me write a "template" for each entity in the list, and repeats it for the number of entities.

Answer (score 0):

not a lot to go on, but here is a start:

```
 for each c in Contracts
     Dim g as new GroupBox
     with g
         .Location = ...   ' needed else it could be off screen
         .Size = ...
     End With

     Dim Lbl as new Label 
     ... set location, text etc
     g.Controls.Add(lbl)
     ... continue for the stuff needed
     g.Controls.Add(otherstuff)

     ' depending on the amount of similarity you can make factories:
     Dim cbo as ComboBOx = MakeContactCBO(someKey)
     g.Controls.Add(cbo) 

     Me/theFormName.Controls.Add(g)            ' add g with all the child ctls
  next c
```

It can get lengthy.  if they are somewhat similar you can several on the form already and then modify or hide them as needed. e.g. a layout that serves 80% of the situations, then remove and add to that base.